# How do i create an akka.net router in f#?

Tags: f#, akka.net

I could not figure out how to create a router actor in f#. And the f# Api page does not offer much help either. Any sample code is very much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, in C# you just call `.WithRouter` extension method and provide some configuration. You can do the same in F#. Do you have any C# code that you are struggling to convert to F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define routers via [HOCON config](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers) - this looks the same for both C# and F# versions.

In case of **Akka.FSharp** plugin, you can define router programaticaly: `let actorRef = spawnOpt system actorName actorBehavior [ Router(routerConfig) ]`

In case of **[Akkling](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/wiki/Creating-an-actor)** plugin, you can define it like: `let actorRef = spawn system actorName { props(actorBehavior) with Router = routerConfig }`

Comment: Thank you. Got it working using HOCON and code like so: let workersRef = spawnOpt system "workers" AggregatorActor <|
                [ SpawnOption.Router(Akka.Routing.FromConfig.Instance)]